# Толкование

Tags: фразеология

Здравствуйте. Можно ли истолковать, при прочтении следующего предложения, что речь идет о баллончиках,  которые предназначены для занятий спортом и охотой: «Газовые баллончики принадлежащие В.Т.  является гражданским оружием, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятия спортом, охоты»?
 Заранее Вам благодарен. Владимир

Comment: Учитывая количество граммматических ошибок в примере, вообще трудно что-либо истолковать.

Answer (score 3):

Трудно толковать предложение, в котором числа не числуются, а падежи не падежуются. Но если включить воображение и мысленно исправить ошибки, получится, что баллончики таки предназначены для спорта и охоты.

Comment: Плюс за "числа не числуются, падежи не падежуются" )))